Is there a simple way to fully change user id name in Windows 11 so it doesn't contain a space in it?
With Windows 11 I have a local account user with a user name that contains a space. For example, user name John Doe.
The space has caused issues in the past with some software, and is causing me more issues today.
Is there a simple way to fully change over/migrate the user name to not contain a space, for example to JohnDoe.
The answer should be complete, including changing: The account, profile, registry entries, AppData, paths, access to data in programs like Word, Outlook, etc…

The "simple" way is to create a new user account, log in with it, and copy data over from the old profile to the new account's profile.
Any other methods WILL be complex and carry with them a high chance of causing unforeseen issues.
Because we do not know what, specifically, the issues are this software has with usernames with spaces in them, creating a new user account is, and will be, the best option.
There are several other questions on this site about renaming user profiles which are worth reading because they discuss the problems you'll encounter actually making that change. You will find they also tend to recommend creating a new account and migrating as well:

How do I change a user name in Windows 7?
Windows 10 user rename


Thank you, I was afraid this was the answer I was going to get - esp. as I have many many programs installed on my current account.

@Rob - It's not the only solution. A built-in seamless method is to disconnect the account from  a Microsoft Account, renaming the profile at the prompt, then reconnecting it to the same Microsoft Account  This method works for all version of Windows that supports linking a local account to a MSA.

@Ramhound that is assuming the software issue is due only to the name itself, and not to, say, the folder path to the profile containing spaces, or some registry key containing a space, or something else. That is what I was alluding to when I note the complexities and unforeseen issues. The consensus is that, as long as Windows has had name profile folders, if you need to fully change a username and have that change propagate across the profile folder path, the registry, and all other places in the system, the correct way that avoids most of the issues is to create a new user.

@music2myear - The process I describe changes the name of the process and it’s folder

It would be great if there is an option for this now, but does it update application paths? Also, I Would be very interested in seeing that written out as an answer. More good answers is good, even if I lose the "answered" mark, that isn't something I'm concerned about, especially for a better answer.

Well I ended up creating a new account and then moving all my apps over manually.  It was quite an effort, as various apps had their settings stored in different ways.  Not an exercise for the faint of heart. I had to draw on many years of experience, registry searches, exports/imports, file copies, AI tools, web searches, and lots of patience to get through it all.  The processes took several days.   Along the way I opened a ms feedback feature request for this.  If you're here dealing with the same problem please upvote it for the sake of future generations: https://aka.ms/AAs71wx
